# Remove any kind of quotes from a string in python

Tags: python, replace, python-re

**Example Strings:**

```
'" "Hello World" "'
'" Today isn't a good day for hello world"'
'" Today "is" a good day for hello world "'
```

**Output:**

```
'"Hello World'"
'"Today isnt a good day for hello world'"
'"Today is a good day for hello world'"
```

I tried string replace but I cannot do `str.replace("\"'", "")`. Is there a good way to do it using regular expression or even simply replace method?

Comment: `strip` perhaps?

Comment: strip is generally used for the first and the last character in the string.

Comment: The only hacky way to do which I know is ```str.replace("'", "").replace('"','')```

Comment: Wait, are the quotes around `"is"` supposed to remain? Or any quotes removed?

Comment: `strip(characters)` would have presented itself after a peek at the docs

Comment: @tdelaney I just updated the output. All I want is to remove all the internal quotes from a string.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel: It would. But it would be wrong. `strip` only replaces the characters at the beginning and end of the string; `"a'b".strip('\'"')` wouldn't remove the embedded quote.

Comment: Yes but the embedded quotes were retained in the original desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

You could call replace twice.

You could use str.translate:

```py
>>> s = '" "Hello World" "'
>>> remove_quotes = str.maketrans('', '', "'\"")
>>> s.translate(remove_quotes)
' Hello World '
```

You could use a regular expression.

Any of these approaches would work.

Answer (score 0):

[Use `str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to perform both replacements at once.

```
quote_dropper = str.maketrans('', '', '\'"')  # Ideally done once up front, and reused

# ... later, when you need to strip quotes from a string ...
mystr = mystr.translate(quote_dropper)
```

`str.maketrans` just makes a simple `dict` mapping the codes for both characters to `None`, which is how you tell `translate` to delete said characters when encountered.

Comment: the above seems to be an interesting choice but I don't think it works on Python2. Works perfectly fine on Python3 though.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, the `translate` method is *very* different on Python 2 (or more precisely, it's roughly the same for Python 2 `unicode`, but different for Python 2 `str`, which has a `translate` closer to Python 3's `bytes.translate`). On Python 2 for `str`, you wouldn't need to make a translation table, you'd just do `mystr.translate(None, '\'"')`. I didn't include it in the answer because Python 2 is no longer supported at all, as of this past January, so if you're writing new code in Python 2, you have problems.